# Busybox syslog enable/disable klogd

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, busybox

I know I can configure busybox to be built with `klogd` (`CONFIG_KLOGD`) and it works out of the box.

I'd like to know, though, if I can enable/disable this feature at run-time by a command-line switch or syslog-startup.conf option without need to recompile busybox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I really rather have anyone else's response but since no one else came, I think my own solution is better than no solution, just in case someone else needs it.

I have dug into the sources and it looks like there is no command-line switch or config option to selectively enable/disable `klogd`.

The init-script, though, provides a very nice way of doing that.

1.*Start/Stop* of syslogd and klogd are separated lines:

```
start)
    echo -n "Starting syslogd/klogd: "
    start-stop-daemon -S -b -n syslogd -a /sbin/syslogd -- -n $SYSLOG_ARGS
    start-stop-daemon -S -b -n klogd -a /sbin/klogd -- -n
    echo "done"
```

The ugliest think one could think now is that, if `klogd` is not to be started, simply comment that line out.

2. `/etc/syslog-startup.conf` is simply sourced by `/etc/init.d/syslog`, before the `start)` case:

(basically the first thing in script)

```
if [ -f /etc/syslog-startup.conf ]; then
    . /etc/syslog-startup.conf
```

Well, I can add a variable to `/etc/syslog-startup.conf` that I can test in the init script to selectively enable/disable the `start-stop-daemon ... klog`.

```
start)
    echo -n "Starting syslogd/klogd: "
    start-stop-daemon -S -b -n syslogd -a /sbin/syslogd -- -n $SYSLOG_ARGS
    [ "$KLOGD_DISABLE" = "yes" ] || \
        start-stop-daemon -S -b -n klogd -a /sbin/klogd -- -n
    echo "done"
```

Since I am adding a non-standard variable to a config file, it is still very ugly but I feel it less ugly than the first one, so that's what I propose as solution.